# Почему INSERT с подключением к одной базе, внутри цикла, выводящего SELECT дает ошибку SELECT-a?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, база-данных

Всем привет!

На моем хостинге есть два сайта, у каждого своя бд. На обоих сайтах Wordpress. Хотел перенести все новости одной категории с одного сайта на другой. Меня тут уже просветили, что для этого в Wordpress есть готовый механизм. Но сначала я пытался это сделать Select-ом в в старой бд и INSERT-ом в новой. И меня мучает вопрос, почему вот это не работает:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";

$servername2 = "localhost";
$database2 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$username2 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$password2 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$conn2 = mysqli_connect($servername2, $username2, $password2, $database2);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts";

$counter = 600;

$iterator = 1;

if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
    foreach($result as $row){

        $stringArr[] = "(" . $counter . ", '" . $row['post_author'] . "', '" . $row['post_date'] . "', '" . $row['post_date_gmt'] . "',
        '" . $row['post_content'] . "', '" . $row['post_title'] . "', '" . $row['post_excerpt'] . "',
        '" . $row['post_status'] . "', '" . $row['comment_status'] . "', '" . $row['ping_status'] . "',
        '" . $row['post_password'] . "', '" . $row['post_name'] . "', '" . $row['to_ping'] . "',
        '" . $row['pinged'] . "', '" . $row['post_modified'] . "', '" . $row['post_modified_gmt'] . "',
        '" . $row['post_content_filtered'] . "', '" . $row['post_content_filtered'] . "', " . $row['post_parent'] . ",
        '" . $row['guid'] . "', " . $row['menu_order'] . ", '" . $row['post_type'] . "', '" . $row['post_mime_type'] . "',
        " . $row['comment_count'] . ")"; 
/*        
        if($iterator%50 == 0) {
            print_r($stringArr);

            exit;
        }*/
        $iterator++;
        $counter++;
 /*       
        print_r($string);
        
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO serjam_wp1.wp_post VALUES (" . $string . ")";

        if ($conn2->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
          echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
          echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
```

Если убрать INSERT во вторую базу, то прекрасно все выводится в браузер из первой базы. Ко как только $sql2 использует INSERT - все...

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что не работает? Если есть ошибки, добавьте их к вопросу

Comment: `$sql2 = "INSERT INTO serjam_wp1.wp_post VALUES (" . $string . ")";` что такое `$string` и откуда Вы его берете?

Comment: @SwaD к сожалению, не могу уже посмотреть код, но почему не работало - интересно..

Comment: Потому что в Вашем коде, как минимум не существует переменной `$string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$string не определено, поэтому $sql2 не работает:
вы перепутали stringArr и string